# Count the number of Strings in a String

Tags: java, string, indexof

I'm trying to count the number of symbol (String) occurrences within a text (String). I've seen some other solutions here, but they're more advanced or use libraries. My idea is to reduce the string at each occurrence of the symbol. I use `.indexOf(symbol,1)` to search for symbol from index 1 because if it searches at 0 it just stops. However, the code overcounts by one most of the time.

```
String text = readLine("Enter text");
String symbol = readLine("Enter symbol");

int count = 0;
while (true) {
    if (!text.contains(symbol)) {
        break;
    }
    count++;
    if ((text.indexOf(symbol, 1)) == -1) {
        break;
    }
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf(symbol, 1));
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(count);
}

System.out.println("Symbol " + symbol + " appears in text " + count + " times.");
```

Please help me find the flaw in logic, and also tell me if this approach is good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!text.contains(symbol)) {
    break;
}
count++;
if ((text.indexOf(symbol, 1)) == -1) {
    break;
}
```

This part of your code is quite problematic. You increment the count if the symbol is present in the text, even if it is the first character - while your

```
text = text.substring(text.indexOf(symbol, 1));
```

code assures that the first character is the specified symbol in the text. This causes your code to overcount by one if it contains the specified symbol. To fix it, change your code to

```
while (true) {
    if (!text.contains(symbol)) {
        break;
    }
    count++;
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf(symbol)+1);//+1 so it starts at the next character
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

As you can see, the first character is no longer the specified symbol. This ensures that

1. The `contains()` method is enough to determine the presence of the symbol
2. The `count` is set correctly

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response! Would you say that this approach (with substrings) is good? Or is it problematic perhaps performance wise? My friend told me that manipulating strings like this is usually a bad practice but he didn't really elaborate on why.

Comment: Well generally it would be better to use some kind of iterator for counting the symbols, since it doesn't include object creation. I don't think it is much of a performance loss for String though, it is really optimised in Java. If you want a cheat-like solution you can use the replace() method and compare the initial length with the final size, which is pretty much the iterator solution but instead of counting it removes the symbol from the string. It still gives the result in the end though

Comment: Example for the replacing method: String s=text.replace(symbol, ""); int count=(text.length()-s.length())/symbol.length();

Comment: @tibetiroka: that example using `replace()` will throw an `ArithmeticException` if `symbol` is empty.

Comment: @LukeWoodward And contains() always finds the empty string, indexOf() will always return 0, and basically every method will return unexpected results. Handling these corner cases is not part of the general algorithm. Actually, what do you think the correct answer is when the symbol is empty? You cannot specify a number which indicates how many times it is present. (You can use negatives for handling that, but then you still have to check it before moving on to the algorithm)

Comment: @tibetiroka: in my opinion, the correct solution when `symbol` is empty is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a message that explains the reason why `symbol` cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since tibetiroka has already identified the flaw in your code, I'll only tackle the second part of your question:

> also tell me if this approach is good or bad.

It works, but it is both quite complicated and not very efficient at runtime. The reason is that `substring()` copies all remaining characters into a new string. For instance, suppose your text contains the symbol 1000 times, and nothing else. Then, after finding the first symbol, your code will copy the 999 remaining symbols, and 998 after finding the second symbol, and so on, for a total of about 500 000 symbol copies, even though there are only 1000 symbols in the text!

It is therefore better to avoid `substring()`, and instead use the second parameter to `indexOf()` to resume looking after the last symbol found:

```
int count = 0;
int index = 0;
while (true) {
    index = text.indexOf(symbol, index); // find next occurrence of symbol
    if (index == -1) {
      return count;
    }
    count++;
    index++;
}
```

I've also eliminated the use of `contains()`, since `indexOf()` already tells us if there is another occurrence.

One last thing: You didn't specify whether overlapping symbols should be counted. For instance, if we look for "aba" in the text "ababa", is that one or two occurrences? If occurrences shouldn't overlap, we can achieve this by saying `index += symbol.length` whenever we find a symbol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond, your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `substring` is to keep track of the previous index the string was found at and use [`String#indexOf(str, fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)).

```
int count = 0;
for(int idx = -1; (idx = text.indexOf(symbol, idx + 1)) != -1; count++);
System.out.println("Symbol " + symbol + " appears in text " + count + " times.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following:

```
String text = readLine("Enter text");
char symbol = readLine("Enter symbol").charAt(0);

int count = 0;
for(char character: text.toCharArray()) {
    if(symbol == character) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Count: " + count);
```

This just loops through each character of the string and compares it to the entered symbol

Comment: the symbol is a string, not a character